# processes characteristic of nonliving matter

Tags: grammar, meaning

> The materialist standpoint, however, which rejects the mechanistic
> idea that all forms of motion of matter can be reduced to mechanical
> motion, must not be confused with the idealist notion that the higher
> forms of motion cannot be explained as arising from the lower forms.
> For example, idealists assert that life, as a form of motion of
> matter, cannot possibly be derived from any **processes** **characteristic
> of nonliving matter**.

Materialism and the Dialectical Method - Maurice Cornforth

I don't know the construct used there.

Why did the author put two nouns together? (process + characteristic)

Comment: *Characteristic* is an adjective in this instance, not a noun.  *Processes [that are] characteristic of nonliving matter.*